# Java - using Thread instead of SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety, swingworker

I cannot really get the advantage of using a swingworker instead of just simply putting the heavy task in a (simple) background-thread.

This is just a codesnippet but shows the task of counting an integer and putting the values in a JLabel. (this is within the ActionPerformed)

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
            counter++;
            label.setText(Integer.toString(counter));       
        }
    }
};

t.start();
```

Instead of this simple codesnippet I have been told to use the abstract SwingWorker-class and override methods such as **doInBackground**, **process** and **done**.

It works very fine when the label is updating simply using **Thread**. Why should I create a new class that extends swingworker and implement the abstract methods?
I can at the moment only think of the Swing-worker as threadsafe, is that the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swing is not thread safe, modifying the UI outside of the context of the EDT, like you are will, cause random paint artifacts and dirty paint issues which will be near impossible to track down.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

The `publish` method of the `SwingWorker` pushes the update onto the a queue, which is processed within the EDT and pushed to the `process` method.  `done` is also called within the context of the EDT, making it safe to update the UI from

Now, you could use something like...

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        int counter = 0 ;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
            counter++;
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    label.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

t.start();
```

And under Java 8+ you probably won't have to many issues, but Java 6 can be finicky about needing a `final` variable for anonymous classes, which is why I generally avoid it.

`SwingWoker` also has progress support via it's `setProgress` method and `PropertyChangeListener`, which is also another way you can provide feedback...

Comment: "effective final" variables were introduced in Java 8, not Java 7 ;)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I knew it was in there somewhere